# C#: Unassigned local variable with succeeded property pattern match

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I have the following code using pattern matching with a property pattern that always succeeds:

```
var result = new { Message = "Hello!" } is { Message: string message };
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

The above match succeeds(result is `true`). However, when I try to print `message`, I get a:

```
CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable.
```

However, the following works:

```
var result = "Hello!" is { Length: int len };
Console.WriteLine(len);
```

Also, when I use it with an `if`, it just works fine:

```
if (new { Message = "Hello!"} is { Message: string message }) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Why the discrepancies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the discrepancies?

Well, it's a *compile-time* error, and at *compile-time*, it doesn't know that it would match. As far as the compiler is concerned, it's absolutely valid for `result` to be false, and `message` to be unassigned - therefore it's a compile-time error to try to use it.

In your second example, the compiler knows that it will always match because *every* string has a length, and in the third example you're only trying to use the pattern variable *if* it's matched.

The only oddity/discrepancy here is that the compiler doesn't know that `new { Message = "Hello!" }` will always match `{ Message: string message }`. I can understand that, in that `Message` could be null for the same anonymous type... slightly more oddly, it looks like it doesn't know that it will always match `{ Message: var message }` either (which should match any non-null reference to an instance of the anonymous type, even if `Message` is null).

I suspect that for your string example, the compiler is "more aware" that a string literal can't be null, therefore the pattern really, really will always match - whereas for some reason it doesn't do that for the anonymous type.

I note that if you extract the string literal to a separate variable, the compiler doesn't know it will always match:

```cs
string text = "hello";
var result = text is { Length: int length };
// Use of unassigned local variable
Console.WriteLine(length);
```

I *suspect* this is because a string literal is a constant expression, and that the compiler effectively has more confidence about what it can predict for constant expressions.

I agree that it does look a *bit* odd, but I'd be surprised if this actually affected much real code - because you don't tend to pattern match against string literals, and I'd say it's the string literal match that is the unexpected part here.

Comment: I just tried the same(extracting to a separate variable) with a `DateTime` and somehow it works. (`var now = DateTime.Now; var r = now is { Day: int days };
Console.WriteLine(days);`)

Comment: @AmalK: That should be fine, because `DateTime` is a struct. There is *no* variable value for `now` that could fail to match that expression. Whereas in the `text` example in the code in my answer, if you imagine changing `text` to null in the debugger, that would no longer match the pattern.

Comment: Seems like the difference really is classes and structs. Got it to work with a custom struct but doesn't work for a class

Comment: @AmalK: Except that string is a class. So there's still the oddity there. I'm not surprised that it works against a struct where that will always match.